# Mongoose preventing saving two documents and sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm running into an issue using Mongoose, Express where I want to save a sub document to my user by pushing it into the sub document array, which I can do. However the issues arise when I want to delete a gamesession that is stored in the users "sessions" attribute and also delete the gamesession globally. I think the issue arises because I'm saving two seperate instances of a gamesession. Here is the code for creating a new sub document called "gamesession" and pushing it onto the users "session" attribute

```
//POST /posts
// Route for creating gamesessions for specific user
router.post("/gamesessions/:uID/", function(req, res, next) {
    var gamesession = new GameSession(req.body);
    req.user.sessions.push(gamesession);
    gamesession.postedBy = req.user._id;
    req.user.save(function(err, user) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        gamesession.save(function(err, gamesession){
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(gamesession);
            res.status(201);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my UserSchema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    posts: [PostSchema],
    sessions: [GameSessionSchema],
    email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
});
```

And my GameSessionSchema

```
var GameSessionSchema = new Schema({
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    region: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    game: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    age: String,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    platform: {
      type: [String], 
      enum: ["Xbox One", "PS4", "PC"],
      required: true
    }
});
```

Edit: Adding my delete route to see if that helps

```
//DELETE /posts/:id/comments/:id
//Delete a specific comment
router.delete("/gamesessions/:uID/sessions/:gID", function(req, res) {
    var gamesession = new GameSession(req.body);
    gamesession.remove(function(err) {
        req.user.save(function(err, user) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(user);
        });
    });
});
```

Then, when I want to delete a gamesession with a route, it only deletes the instance saved in user.sessions and when I want to query all gamesessions, it's still there, but deleted in my User document. Any ideas? I think it's because I'm saving the document twice, and if so, what's the best way to save it in user.sessions while also being able to delete from user.sessions and querying a global session.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not saving the removed gamesession from the GameSession document?

`router.delete("/gamesessions/:uID/sessions/:gID", function(req, res) {
    var gamesession = new GameSession(req.body);
    gamesession.remove(function(err) {
        req.user.save(function(err, user) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            gamesession.save(function(err, gamesession){
              if(err) return next(err);
              res.json({message: 'Updated GameSession Doc'}, gamesession)
            })
            res.json(user);
        });
    });
});`

Comment: I'm getting a 404 not found error using this code. I know for a fact my uID and gID parameters get the user and gamesession to be deleting. It's just that it only deletes the game session that I query for all game sessions with, but when I query users it is still appearing in the user json response as a sub document.